# Xcode "edit all in scope" stopped working

Tags: xcode, editor

Is there some place to turn this feature on and off?  I was using it for a long time but now it doesn't pop up any more.

Comment: http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?PHPSESSID=5fmk04ifnt67mijri15pfujg47&topic=1456.msg4120#msg4120

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately in XCode 8.3, having the annoying highlighting disabled also disables the Ctrl-Cmd-E keyboard shortcut (and the corresponding Editor menu item). This differs from 8.2 and earlier and took me ages to track down, so I'm posting the answer here in case anyone else comes looking for a solution. (You just need to check the "Highlight instances of selected symbol" option in the Preferences->Text Editing pane).

Comment: What a dumb change indeed

Answer (score 2):

On XCode 4 or XCode 5, try Control+Cmd+E. The little arrow doesn't appear to me anymore, but the shortcut still works. :)